# Query string (uri syntax) for a RESTFul API request

Tags: rest, web-services, restful-url, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm very new to REST and google cloud endpoints. I've followed the tutorial 
[Getting Started with Endpoints Frameworks on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java) and I've executed the API query as stated in the tutorial successfully:

> > curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"message":"hello world"}'  http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo

But I didn't manage it to find the corresponding URI query statement to be used in the browser.

I tried

- http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo?{"message":"hello world"}
- http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo?=message="hello world"

and a lot of combinations without success and which resulted in receiving no response.

How does the URI statement, corresponding to the cURL request as stated above, look like?

Thank you in advance.

---

BTW: This is the endpoint implementation of the API method "echo":

```
@ApiMethod(name = "echo")
public Message echoPathParameter(Message message, @Named("n") int n) {
return doEcho(message, n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the man page of `curl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl):

> -d/--data
>
> (HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded` means that the *body* of the request contains

```
message=hello+world
```

Comment: thank you for you quick response. Unfortunately this doesn't work. I tried it. I have used cURL as an example. There is also an Powershell specific request statement in the reference tutorial. So I guess, the URI has to follow another syntax as stated by you.

Comment: I've edited my answer. There is no single URL for such a POST request. You must put the `message` into the body.